# What is this modifier key?

Tags: keyboard

What is the OS X modifier key symbol that looks like the control icon (`^`) but with the addition of a line over it?

Symbol: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the enter key symbol:

`⌤ is enter`

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/making-sense-of-mac-keyboard-symbols/)